# Fill a DTO's List attribute with hibernate named query and spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, named-query

I'm wondering if the following could be achieved with hibernate. considering the following DTO:

```
public class ClassDTO {
    private String className;
    private List<String> studentNames;
    //getters & setters
}
```

and the following hbm file containing the sql-query:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="app.ClassDTO">
        <id name="className" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="studentNames" type="java.lang.List" />
    </class>

    <sql-query name="classQuery">
        <return alias="class" class="app.ClassDTO" />
            select classTable.CLASS_NAME AS {class.className}, ST.STUDENT_NAME
             from CLASS classTable
            join STUDENT ST on ST.CLASS_ID=classTable.CLASS_ID
            where ST.age<18
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

if we run the query in the Database we'll get the following result :

```
+----------+------------+
|CLASS_NAME|STUDENT_NAME|
+----------+------------+
|  CS106   |   BILL     |
|  CS106   |   GEORGE   |
|  CS106   |   MICHEL   |
|  ELEC8   |   WILL     |
|  ELEC8   |   MIKE     |
|  ELEC8   |   BETTY    |
+----------+------------+
```

if we run the query in hibernate, we're supposed to get a List of ClassDTO objects. but is it possible to initialize those objects in the following manner?

```
List<ClassDTO> result = getHibernateTemplate.findByNamedQuery("classQuery").;
resul.size(); //<-- the list size should be 2 (one entry for CS106 and another for ELEC8)
result.get(0).getStudentNames().size(); //<-- the size should be 3 for BILL, GEORGE and MICHEL who are linked to the class CS106
```

I've searched through hibernate documentation but i haven't succeeded in finding any answer yet. any help is really apreciated.
thanks in advance guys.

Comment: what i'm looking for is some sort of a group by operation that would select distinct names of classes and fill their `studentLists` with the multiple student names per class.

Comment: Is it not classic One to Many Relationship? Or am I missing something? Couple of examples on the web : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/ , http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/ etc. I think the hibernate mapping shown in these examples is better and more Hibernate-ish. They have the 'many' part as a set, which I suppose should not be a problem.

Comment: the example you gave me is in fact about entities with one-to-many relation-ships, what I have is a DTO (not persisted), i just want to fill it up as such. both the class and the student  **entities** (not shown in my question) have other attributes of course in which I'm not interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you normalize your data a little further and tweak your mapping you can get Hibernate to do this automatically:

```
<class name="app.ClassDTO">
    <id name="className" type="java.lang.String" />
    <list name="studentNames" table="class_student">
    <key column="class_name" />
        <element type="string"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

I'll admit, if the only only data present really are these 2 columns then normalization seems silly.  But to a large extent, having Hibernate automatically convert flat table data to a complex object structure requires following certain rules (I'll stop short of calling it a best practice in this particular case).

If you want to leave the table like it is, then you'll need to create the ClassDTO on your own, which really isn't that hard:

```
final List<Object[]> resultObjects = getSession().getNamedQuery().list();
public Map<String, ClassDTO> resultMap = new HashMap<>(String, ClassDTO);
for (Object[] result : resultObjects) {
    // find ClassDTO in map for class, or create new one
    // add student name to class dto instance
}
```